# How to increase scroll top with jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to increase scroll top after each click and wrote this for it but it works just first time. In each call value of x is 30, how can I solve it?

I try it on w3schools website and it works there

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
 $(function () {
        $("#btncl").click(function (e) {
             var x = $("div").scrollTop() + 30;
            $("div").scrollTop(x);

        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 150px; overflow: auto">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/2.jpg" />
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<br>
    <input type="button" value="Return the vertical position of the scrollbar" id="btncl">

</form>
```

Comment: works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/tZLVb/

Comment: yes it works there but doesn't work in my form in asp.net

Comment: try unbind('click') before and check if you have errors or try with scrollTo() methode

Comment: can you explain a little.I couldn't inderstand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$(function () {
    var x = $("div").scrollTop();
    $("#btncl").click(function (e) {
        x += 30;
        $("div").scrollTop(x);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function () {
    var incr = 0;
    $("#btncl").click(function (e) {
        incr += 30;
        var x = $("div").scrollTop() + incr;
        $("div").scrollTop(x);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

or?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: @Farkhonde yes, in server the first resource can request as `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js` , i test it in filesystem,so it request as `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js` :)

Comment: @Farkhonde may be your code is not equal with the code in your question ，because it work ok on all browser in my pc。 like WhyMe say,give the `div` a id.

Answer (score 0):

seems to work for me, see the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RdvS/).

Html

```
<div id='abcd' style="border: 1px solid black; height: 150px; overflow: auto">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="80px" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" height="70px" alt="" class="img_gallery"
                src="Images_slider/2.jpg" />
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<br>
    <input type="button" value="Return the vertical position of the scrollbar" id="btncl" />
```

Javascript

```
document.body.onclick=function(e){console.log('ok');$('#abcd').scrollTop($('#abcd').scrollTop() +30);}
```